# Node.js : show process while copying files

Tags: node.js, fs

I wrote a function to copy a directory to another... But there's a problem : I use callback function to send the copied size. This callback comes too early (before the end of the copy). I think the problem is that the process is asynchronous. Can you help me?

```
var fs=require('fs');
var copyDir=function copyDir(from, to, callback){
if(!fs.existsSync(to)){
    fs.mkdirSync(to);
}
console.log(from+" ==> "+to);
var count = 0;
fs.readdir(from, function(err,files){
    for(var i=0;i<files.length;i++){
        var f = from+"/"+files[i];
        var d = f.replace(from, to);
        console.log(f+" ("+i+")"+ " : "+d);
        if(!fs.existsSync(d)){
            if(!fs.statSync(f).isFile()){
                    //fs.mkdirSync(f.replace(from, to));
                    count += fs.statSync(f).size;
                    console.log(f + " will make an inception!")
                    copyDir(f, f.replace(from, to), function(err, cp){callback(err, cp)});
                }else{
                    var size = fs.statSync(f).size;
                    copyFile(f, f.replace(from, to), function(err){
                        if(err) callback(err, count)
                    });
                    count += size;
                    callback(null, count);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
function copyFile(source, target, cb) {
    fs.readFile(source, function (err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
    fs.writeFileSync(target, data, function (err, data){
        if(err) throw err;
        cb(null, fs.statSync(source).size); //This callback comes before the copy end.
    });
    });
}
exports.copyDir = copyDir;
```

copyDir is called by:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){   
console.log('connection');
socket.on('startCopy', function(data){
    sizeDir('templates', function(e, r){
        copyDir('templates', 'tmp', function(err, cp){
            console.log("copy % " + Math.round(100*cp/r));
            socket.emit('copy', {prog: Math.round(100*cp/r)});
        });
    });

});
});
```

Comment: Do you realize that not all your paths call the callback? You have at least one `if` without an `else` in whose case the callback never gets called.

Comment: Can you share the piece of code that you are using to invoke your function?

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo I realize, it's just a trick to do not copy existing files. I will edit my post with the code

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite your `else` code with following:

```
(function() {
    var size = fs.statSync(f).size;
    copyFile(f, f.replace(from, to), function(err){
        if(err) {
            callback(err, count);
            return;
        }
        count += size;
        callback(null, count);
    });
})();
```

But, you have a lot of synchronous function in your code. You should know about all caveats of this approach. [This article](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/12/node-js-synchronous-and-asynchronous-functions.html) may be helpful

Comment: I have synchro functions because my function will fail (why?) with async code.
BTW, why return?

Comment: Because you call your `callback` with `err` if error occurs, so you don't need to call `callback` again for that file

Comment: I've just corrected my code, because previous version didn't work properly. I used closure to wrap `size` variable and `copyFile` to ensure current `size` variable belongs to current file

Comment: like that?
`else{ (function(){}) }`